# How would I fix AttributeError: 'Guild' object has no attribute 'guild' in on_guild_join function | discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

When the bot joins the server I want it to create roles, category, channel. But it give me this. It is written in cogs

It gives me this error

```
Ignoring exception in on_guild_join
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jerry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\Jerry\Documents\Dump-Bot\cogs\welcome.py", line 12, in on_guild_join
    guild = ctx.guild
AttributeError: 'Guild' object has no attribute 'guild'
```

Code:

```
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_guild_join(self, ctx):
        guild = ctx.guild
        await ctx.guild.create_role(name="Muted")
        Muted_role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="Muted")
        await ctx.Muted_role.set_permissions(send_messages=False)
        verify_role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="Member")
        await ctx.verify_role.set_permissions(send_messages=True)
        ticket_category = discord.utils.get(guild.categories, name="Tickets") 

        if ticket_category is None: 
            await guild.create_category_channel(name="Tickets")

        await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(name="welcome")

        guild_join_embed = discord.Embed(title="Thanks for adding me")
        guild_join_embed.add_field(name="Thanks for adding me!", value="It helps alot. I will provide my best support", inline=True)
        guild_join_embed.set_footer(text=f"Right now I am in {len(client.guilds)} guilds/servers")
        await ctx.send(embed=guild_join_embed)
        await ctx.guild.create_voice_channel(name=f"Total Member Count: {guild.member_count}")
        await ctx.guild.create_voice_channel(name=f"Boost Count: {guild.premium_subscription_count}")
        await ctx.guild.create_voice_channel(name=f"Ticket Count: {ticket_category.children.size}") 
        member_count_vc = discord.utils.get(guild.channel, name=f"Total Member Count: {guild.member_count}", category=None)
        server_boost_count_vc = discord.utils.get(guild.channel, name=f"Boost Count: {guild.premium_subscription_count}", category=None)
        ticket_count_vc = discord.utils.get(guild.channel, name=f"Ticket Count: {ticket_category.children.size}", category=None)
        await ctx.member_count_vc.set_permissions(ctx.guild.verify_role, connect=False)
        await ctx.server_boost_count_vc.set_permissions(ctx.guild.verify_role, connect=False)
```

How would I fix this error?

Comment: Events do NOT ever take `ctx` as the parameter.. Please **READ** the docs, it cannot be clearer, https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_guild_join#discord.on_guild_join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your error suggests, you've got an instance of `Guild`, not `Context`. A look at the [API docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_guild_join#discord.on_guild_join) also gives:

> Parameters:
> guild (Guild) – The guild that was joined.

which means `on_guild_join` doesn't get `ctx`, it gets a `Guild` (being the guild that you just joined). To "fix this", remove `.guild`, *you already have the guild*.